# I am not able to break a string when sending it through mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail, smtpclient

When I use this to send mail the body string does not breaks for which I used

```
NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential("bhavik778@gmail.com", mypassword);
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress("bhavik778@gmail.com");
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(tomyclient));
msg.Subject = "Message from CLB Website.";
msg.Body = "Following message was sent to you :-<br/>" + name + "<br/>" + email_id + "<br/>" + Query;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
client.EnableSsl = false;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = loginInfo;
client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Have you tried in multiple email programs/websites? The one I use doesn't allow for html tags

Comment: Try to replace <br> tags with "\r\n"?

Comment: I can send the string but it does not breaks where I want.. To be specific I want Name and email Id to be on different line..  When I used other smtp of my website i.e. itadventure.in it breaks but using gmail it doesn't..

Comment: He is using `IsBodyHtml = true` so HTML breaks should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<br/>` tags get escaped so that they do not have an effect on the e-mail's HTML structure. This is in case you actually want to use one of those characters in your e-mail message.

The mailsender should convert regular newlines ( `\n` ) to line breaks in the e-mail, use those instead.

Comment: I got it.. The reason was gmail skips <br/> as a string and using /n got the answer..

Answer (score 0):

If it works in one email client and not in the other, it might be a problem related to the HTML parsing of the clients. Try using `<br />` instead, with the extra space.

All the suggestions to add newline characters are related to plain-text mail, in HTML mail the newline tags can be ignored by the client, just as they have no meaning in HTML pages. This behaviour will likely be inconsistent across mail clients though.

Comment: I did tried using <br /> but still it wasn't working.. got it done using \n